# How to export a large contacts number via cv or bin/csv/export.php

Tags: import

Both methods seems to have a restriction on a number of contacts processed (25?)

- cv api Contact.get options={"limit":0}
- php export.php  -e Contact > ~/ex.csv

I remember doing some php equilibristics back in the years to get the result and wondering if, maybe, there is hidden parameter ( like "--all" or something ) to get ALL contacts out from the db in 2024?

Comment: When using the api you need to add "limit=0" in order to get all records - otherwise you only get the first 25

Comment: @Fabian Right, I did exactly this in the "cv api Contact.get options={"limit":0}" call - no luck, hence the question.

Comment: I don't know the right syntax for the cli options, but you could try using `cv ev` instead of `cv api` so that you don't have to fight with it, e.g. `cv ev '$r = civicrm_api3("Contact", "get", ["options" => ["limit" => 0]]); print_r($r["values"]);'` (You can play with looping and fputcsv() on the values if you want a csv.)

Comment: @Demerit Thank you, the comment deserves to be the answer. The full code would be something like cv ev '$r = civicrm_api3("Contact", "get", ["options" => ["limit" => 0]]); $fpr = fopen("./res.csv", "w"); foreach ($r["values"] as $rk=>$rv) {fputcsv($fpr, $rv);} fclose($fpr); print_r("done");'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comments you can use `cv ev` instead of `cv api` to avoid having to figure out the cli syntax for limit.

`cv ev '$r = civicrm_api3("Contact", "get", ["options" => ["limit" => 0]]); $fpr = fopen("./res.csv", "w"); foreach ($r["values"] as $rk=>$rv) {fputcsv($fpr, $rv);} fclose($fpr); echo "done";'`

It also occurs to me that core's export.php could probably be updated to default to `"options" => ["limit" => 0]`. Why would anyone ever not want that? At https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/888e65374f208e6d79ff8adc68d0adfa05575277/bin/cli.class.php#L53

Comment: ... or preferably APIv4